# What's the purpose of `host_ptr` parameter in `clCreateBuffer`

Tags: opencl

What's the meaning of the parameter `host_ptr` in `clCreateBuffer?

```
cl_mem clCreateBuffer ( cl_context context,
    cl_mem_flags flags,
    size_t size,
    void *host_ptr,
    cl_int *errcode_ret)
```

It's not really clear from the documentatin:

> host_ptr : A pointer to the buffer data that may already be allocated by
>   the application. The size of the buffer that host_ptr points to must
>   be greater than or equal to the size bytes.

To me it might sound like a host buffer that is going to be copied in the device buffer. However In many examples I see this action is actually performed by `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, and nothing is actually passed to `clCreateBuffer` as `host_ptr` parameter.

Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different uses for the host_ptr parameter, depending on the value passed into the flags parameter. The two flags that use it are `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` & `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`. If flags doesn't contain either of these and host_ptr isn't NULL, the function will give a `CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR` error (see errors on bottom of [clCreateBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) page).

---

### CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR

This basically does as you described, it copies the host_ptr to the devices memory. This provides a convenience by effectively combining `clCreateBuffer` & `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`. Notice that you don't need a command queue as required by `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, the data will be copied to all devices on the context before you use them, how convenient!

As the name suggests, this is a COPY. If you write to this memory on the device, the memory in host_ptr will never see these writes (unless you perform a [clEnqueueReadBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadBuffer.html)). Similarly, if you write to host_ptr after creating the buffer, the memory on the device will not see these writes (unless you perform a [clEnqueueWriteBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBuffer.html)).

### CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Instead of creating a buffer in the device memory, OpenCL will use the memory pointed to by host_ptr directly. If your device is a dedicated GPU on a PCIe connection, this means every time you read or write to this memory in device code, the data has to be sent over PCIe (slow). OpenCL allows the device to create a cache of the data during kernel execution, which helps somewhat. If your device shares physical memory with the host like an integrated GPU, there shouldn't be any such overhead.

Note though you have to be careful to ensure memory consistency. If the host modifies host_ptr while a kernel is working on the memory associated with it (or vice versa), you get undefined behavior.

---

### Which to use?

It depends on what you are doing and what hardware you are working on.
If you aren't too worried about memory copying performance, and want an easy & safe method, use `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`.

### If the device is over PCIe (or other interface)

For large arrays, generally I use `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` and enqueue a read / write as needed. If I'm just writing to an int or small structure, I would use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, just be careful about memory consistency.

If you are *really* interested in memory performance, you may have to look into techniques such as pinned memory ([Reference for AMD GPUs](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide2.pdf#G6.502946)).

### If the device shares host memory (integrated GPU or just CPU device)

If you are confident that the host and device(s) will not read while another is writing, you will be fine using `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` for any size memory objects. For maximum performance, you may have to make sure host_ptr is aligned and a multiple of a certain size (for Intel devices, aligned on a 4 KB boundary and a multiple of 64 bytes). [Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-the-most-from-opencl-12-how-to-increase-performance-by-minimizing-buffer-copies-on-intel-processor-graphics) is more info for zero-copy on Intel hardware.

Comment: Is there a benefit in doing `createBuffer` and then `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` over `createBuffer` with `CL_MEM_CPY_HOST_PTR` or viceversa? What do you mean also with "*the data will be copied to all devices on the context before you use them*"? Wouldn't I do the same with `createBuffer` and `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`?

Comment: The only advantage to doing createBuffer then clEnqueueWriteBuffer I can see if is you use non-blocking writes, which allows the host code to continue while the copying occurs. This won't improve the copying bandwidth though. With CL_MEM_CPY_HOST_PTR, OpenCL has to perform a blocking copy at createBuffer. 
And yes, "the data will be copied to all devices on the context before you use them" would be the same, as createBuffer and clEnqueueWriteBuffer.